# Do not automatically expand all subgrid rows when clicking grouping column's expand icon

Tags: jqgrid

After grouping, is there a way for expand/collapse icon of current row not automatically expand/collapse all of the subgrid's rows?  Just leave it alone as it was.

```
var parmColumnName = 'Model';

$('#test').jqGrid('groupingGroupBy'), 
   parmColumnName, 
   {
       groupCollapse: true,
       groupField: ['name']
   }
);
```

//Original setup after playing around with it.  (See X5 under BMW)

[image]

//Collapse the grouped Make

[image]

//Then Expand the grouped Make  (All of the model are expanded by default, I do not want it to change and I want it to look like the original snapshot above)

[image]

Comment: Do you use subgrids or data grouping only? The grid looks much more as TreeGrid and not as grouping grid with subgrids. The value from VIN column of parent node (BMW for example) seems to have no relation with the values of children (X3, X5, Z3). Could you post more full code what you use? The best would be to post the demo which you use.

Comment: I'm using data grouping (groupingGroupBy).  I'm not using TreeGrid though.  Here's the temporary link to the demo page at https://dealerapp.bookitout.com/zzJqGrid/Inventory1.cshtml .   The link not going to be online for very long.   Just drag the Make column into the box at the top.  Then drag the Model column to the box at teh top as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your question very interesting, but the solution for the problem is not easy. In my opinion the source code of two jqGrid methods `groupingRender` and especially `groupingToggle` should be changed. The solution which I suggest you can see on the demo. The demo overwrites the original code of `groupingRender` and `groupingToggle` methods. More full description of my suggestions you will find below.

First of all I want to describe the problem in my words. You used the words "the subgrid's rows" in the text of your question which bring misunderstanding. What you use is **multilevel grouping**. The first problem in my opinion is the behavior of [groupCollapse: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#options_and_methods) option. In case of multilevel grouping jqGrid collapse currently *only data* instead of all grouping headers till the top level. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandingStateOfSubGroups0.htm) uses 3-level grouping and the option `groupCollapse: true`. It dysplays

[image]

instead of intuitively expected

[image]

Another problem which you formulate in your question is the current behavior of expending. The problem is that if the user have collapsed the nodes to that all looks compact, like on the last picture which I posted, end then the user expand some node **jqGrid expand all children grouping headers of the node till the data**. So if one expand for example only "test1" node then all its children nodes will be expanded instead of expending only *the next grouping level*.

To fix the first problem (opened sub-grouping headers in spite of `groupCollapse: true`) I changed [one line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.grouping.js#L278) of `groupingRender` method from

```js
str += "<tr id=\""+hid+"\" role=\"row\" class= \"ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-"+$t.p.direction+" "+clid+"\"><td style=\"padding-left:"+(n.idx * 12) + "px;"+"\" colspan=\""+colspans+"\">"+icon+$.jgrid.template(grp.groupText[n.idx], gv, n.cnt, n.summary)+"</td></tr>";
```

to

```js
str += "<tr id=\""+hid+"\"" +(grp.groupCollapse && n.idx>0 ? " style=\"display:none;\" " : " ") + "role=\"row\" class= \"ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-"+$t.p.direction+" "+clid+"\"><td style=\"padding-left:"+(n.idx * 12) + "px;"+"\" colspan=\""+colspans+"\">"+icon+$.jgrid.template(grp.groupText[n.idx], gv, n.cnt, n.summary)+"</td></tr>";
```

The main problem which you asked was a little more difficult. Below you can find the fixed version of

```js
$.jgrid.extend({
    groupingToggle : function(hid){
        this.each(function(){
            var $t = this,
            grp = $t.p.groupingView,
            strpos = hid.split('_'),
            uidpos,
            //uid = hid.substring(0,strpos+1),
            num = parseInt(strpos[strpos.length-2], 10);
            strpos.splice(strpos.length-2,2);
            var uid = strpos.join("_"),
            minus = grp.minusicon,
            plus = grp.plusicon,
            tar = $("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(hid)),
            r = tar.length ? tar[0].nextSibling : null,
            tarspan = $("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(hid)+" span."+"tree-wrap-"+$t.p.direction),
            getGroupingLevelFromClass = function (className) {
                var nums = $.map(className.split(" "), function (item) {
                            if (item.substring(0, uid.length + 1) === uid + "_") {
                                return parseInt(item.substring(uid.length + 1), 10);
                            }
                        });
                return nums.length > 0 ? nums[0] : undefined;
            },
            itemGroupingLevel,
            collapsed = false, tspan;
            if( tarspan.hasClass(minus) ) {
                if(grp.showSummaryOnHide) {
                    if(r){
                        while(r) {
                            if($(r).hasClass('jqfoot') ) {
                                var lv = parseInt($(r).attr("jqfootlevel"),10);
                                if(  lv <= num) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            $(r).hide();
                            r = r.nextSibling;
                        }
                    }
                } else  {
                    if(r){
                        while(r) {
                            itemGroupingLevel = getGroupingLevelFromClass(r.className);
                            if (itemGroupingLevel !== undefined && itemGroupingLevel <= num) {
                                break;
                            }
                            $(r).hide();
                            r = r.nextSibling;
                        }
                    }
                }
                tarspan.removeClass(minus).addClass(plus);
                collapsed = true;
            } else {
                if(r){
                    var showData = undefined;
                    while(r) {
                        itemGroupingLevel = getGroupingLevelFromClass(r.className);
                        if (showData === undefined) {
                            showData = itemGroupingLevel === undefined; // if the first row after the opening group is data row then show the data rows
                        }
                        if (itemGroupingLevel !== undefined) {
                            if (itemGroupingLevel <= num) {
                                break;// next item of the same lever are found
                            } else if (itemGroupingLevel === num + 1) {
                                $(r).show().find(">td>span."+"tree-wrap-"+$t.p.direction).removeClass(minus).addClass(plus);
                            }
                        } else if (showData) {
                            $(r).show();
                        }
                        r = r.nextSibling;
                    }
                }
                tarspan.removeClass(plus).addClass(minus);
            }
            $($t).triggerHandler("jqGridGroupingClickGroup", [hid , collapsed]);
            if( $.isFunction($t.p.onClickGroup)) { $t.p.onClickGroup.call($t, hid , collapsed); }
            });
        return false;
    },
});
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandingStateOfSubGroups.htm) demonstrates the results of all changes which I suggest. I'll post the changes as pull request to trirand. I hope that the changes will be included in the main code of jqGrid.

**UPDATED**: I posted [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/526) with the changes which I suggested above.

**UPDATED 2**: My pull request was merged with the main code of jqGrid. The new 4.5.4 version of jqGrid published today includes the changed. [The new demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandingStateOfSubGroups1.htm) uses jqGrid 4.5.4 and it works like you expect. So to fix the problem which you described in your question you need just update jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you Oleg!  I will look into it soon.  So, "Multilevel grouping" is what it's called.  I'll remember that.  I will post a new question of a new problem I had last week Thursday and I'm wondering of a workaround to it.  It is about using jqGrid's beforeRequest event to call "GroupingGroupBy" causing it to go into infinite loop.  :-(

Comment: Yes I know the scripts are a little difficult to use.  I have been given hard projects.  LOL!  I will simplify it better once a few more projects are done and settle down.